# How to mix SoftWeak save strategy with Timebased?

Tags: caffeine

Good day ! Can I mix Time-based and Reference-based stategy ? 
I want cache based on SoftReference with 5 minute lifecycles, can I get it from box ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

You can compose most features together, unless documented as incompatible. In those cases an exception will be thrown by the builder.

```
Cache<K, V> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // or Duration.ofMinutes(5)
    .softValues()
    .build();
```

Please be aware that soft references have a performance impact on the garbage collector and can be finicky. A maximum size is generally preferred, all else being equal.

Comment: Thx you ! I am was searching for this.